# How to factor $n^4 + 2n^3 + n^2 -2n^2c -2nc +c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Since I need to prove that this is square of natural number I tried to transfrom it into combinations of square of binomials,especially $2nc$ and $2n^2c$ with $n^4$ and $n^2$ have caught my eyes ,but I couldn't make it work.
I tried Bézout's identity to find n,c which $P(n)$ or $P(c)$  is zero but it wasnt straightforward.

Can you guys help me out.I am trying to improve my skills of factoring polynomials but sometimes I got stuck I dont know what to do.
I dont want to see only solution but what is going inside your head,how do you reason.what are the steps with which you approach the problem and what made you think towards the way that led to solution.

Comment: To clarify, what is it that you actually want to do? Do you want to show that the expression can never be a square (which could allow for difference approaches), or do you want to just factorize it?

Comment: Sure.Thank you for reply.I need to prove that this expression is square of natural number,c is also natural number

Comment: I also need to appologize.I made small mistake in expression that is now fixed in edit(2n^c instead of 2(n^2)c )

Comment: Hint: what are the perfect squares, and what are the doubled cross terms? And now see which combinations of signs will work.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Expand out $[n(n+1)-c]^2$. In particular, note that simple algebra gives $[n(n+1)-c]^2=n^4+2n^3+n^2-2n^2c -2nc +c^2$, so as the LHS is always the square of an integer if $n$ and $c$ are both integers, so must be the RHS $n^4+2n^3+n^2-2n^2c-2nc +c^2$.

ETA: As far as what led me to this, I did first note that $n^4+2n^3+n^2$ is $n^2(n+1)^2$, and so I figured that if the given polynomial $n^4+2n^3+n^2-2n^2c -2nc +c^2$ were square, the resulting square had to be "close to" $n^2(n+1)^2$ and perhaps the square of $n(n+1)$ "minus something" in $c$,  due to some minus signs in the polynomial, and that led me to the solution. **I had also plugged in $c=1$ and $c=2$ and tried factoring both of the resulting polynomials to guide the way and see if there was a pattern.** Then from there I tried $[n(n+1)-c]^2$ as my first guess. There is a certain amount of trial and error involved.

Comment: You can do it without trial and error by equating the coefficients, but it sometimes may be faster to do trial and error if one has experience with factoring polynomials.

Comment: Thanks I think I learned more from your explaining of how did you attack the problem than just solution.

Comment: @GreyCow thankyou, I am glad you found what I wrote helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to get something in the form $(an^2+bn+d)^2$. (I can't use the variable $c$ as that is taken). Expanding that gives:

$$(an^2+bn+d)^2=(a^2)n^4+(2ab)n^3+(2ad+b^2)n^2+(2bd)n+(d^2)$$

Now it is a matter of equating the coefficients.

$$(a^2)n^4+(2ab)n^3+(2ad+b^2)n^2+(2bd)n+(d^2)=(1)n^4 + (2)n^3 + (1-2c)n^2 +(-2c)n+(c^2)$$

From this, we get that $$a^2=1\Rightarrow a=1$$

Note that I'm taking the $+1$ root just to find one answer. You'll get another answer if you take the negative root.

$2ab=2$, where $a=1$, so $2(1)b=2$ so $b=1$. To continue this process for the $n^2$ term, $2ad+b^2=1-2c$ where $a=1$ and $b=1$. This means that $2(1)d+(1)^2=1-2c$. Therefore, $d=-c$. For the linear coefficient, our values of $b$ and $d$ remain consistent. For the constant coefficient, note that the value we found is still consistent meaning we have no contradictions. Therefore, the values we found are correct!

So, $$[an^2+bn+d]^2=[(1)n^2+(1)n+-c]^2$$

$$\fbox{
    \( 
(n^2+n-c)^2=(1)n^4 + (2)n^3 + (1-2c)n^2 +(-2c)n+(c^2)    \)
}$$

---

Since your polynomial can be expressed as a square, where the $n^2+n-c$ is always going to be an integer (for integer values of $n$ and $c$), you know that the polynomial is a square of that quadratic (which is always going to be an integer).

Comment: Thank you it helped enormoulsy,I don't really understand what are you talking about near the end of your answer :  " For the linear coefficient, our values of b
 and d
 remain consistent. For the constant coefficient, note that the value we found is still consistent meaning we have no contradictions. Therefore, the values we found are correct!"

Comment: I just meant that we had already found all the variables we needed to find, namely $a$, $b$, and $d$. Linear coefficient by the way just means the coefficient of $n$. Constant coefficient means the constant term. What I meant to describe was that if you continued with this process of equating coefficients, you wouldn't find any contradictions. It would be weird if you already got $2bd=-2c$ (for $n$ coefficient), but it didn't align with your already set definitions for $b$ and $d$. Here though, since $b=1$ and $d=-c$, the equation still works.

Comment: I get it now.Thank you very much.I learned a lot.My mind will be occupied with finding scenarios when it is possible to use method of equating coefficients to factor and when there is no solution.Thank you again,intresting method.